# Formula never evaluates false

Tags: excel, formula

I have a formula
=IF(AND(AG6="yes",AL6="yes"),"Both",IF(AND(AG6="no",AL6="no"),"Neither",IF(AG6="Yes",1,2)))

It just looks for values and then substitutes a value depending on what it finds.

The problem is that it always finds an answer even if all of the cells it is looking at are blank.  What I want is for it to display some type of error - FALSE for instance - if the formula is not satisfied.

I'm sure it's simple...  And it seems like I've hit this before.

Thanks in advance.
Phil

Comment: In the last part `2)))`, just change 2 with `IF(AL6="yes",2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.  Not totally sure, but it seems that by adding another conditional at the end it will now return blanks if the formula goes unsatisfied.

=IF(AQ11=1,1,IF(AQ11=2,2,IF(AR11=1,1,IF(AR11=2,2,IF(AU11=1,1,IF(AU11=2,2,""))))))

Comment: That formula seems very different than the one in your question, but just a small tip - you can use Alt+Enter in the formula and spaces for indentation